# SQL Server on Mac with Docker : Login failed for user 'sa'.

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to work with SQL Server on my Mac with Docker. 
I have already installed the image and I'm running the SQL Server.

[image]

When I run the above code and check the running containers using 'docker ps' the container is always stopped. Therefore I ran the following command to start the container with the container id.

docker start 0e84faabe9b35b2e4e8e39be3f389b38c151a3a6e7c3c82995f3ea6dc0e8ed1e
Then the sql container keeps running.

I want to connect to the sql server with VS Code but the message keep saying **Login failed for user 'sa'** 
I have installed the sql-cli to check the sql connection but it didn't work as well.

I tried to connect to sql server with the following credentials:
mssql -u sa -p sa123! which I given to start the sql container.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

[image]

This is what I'm getting in VS Code.

[image]

Comment: Not at a proper computer to check, but I drove myself crazy when I used `$` in my passwords and would then have to escape them. Did you try escaping the bang (`'sa123\!'`)? (You might also try starting the container with a more complex password in the first place - that one doesn't seem strong enough to pass basic validation, which might also explain why it doesn't start up initially.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Debugging:

Let's start the container:

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ sudo docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e SA_PASSWORD='sa123!' -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -i microsoft/mssql-server-linux   
0031f2c49b66596cb8dc8cfec6d14351406fb924e39bd8227dfbcf7e23b67d54
```

The container is not running :(

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
0031f2c49b66        microsoft/mssql-server-linux   "/bin/sh -c /opt/m..."   21 seconds ago      Exited (1) 15 seconds ago                       festive_meninsky
```

Let's look at the logs:

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ sudo docker logs 0031f2c49b66596cb8dc8cfec6d14351406fb924e39bd8227dfbcf7e23b67d54 
Configuring Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)...
Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R) setup failed with error code 1. Please check the setup log in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.
```

Oh, okay, let's see. Start the container again:

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ sudo docker start 0031f2c49b66                                                                                                                                                                  
0031f2c49b66
```

Is it running now?

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
0031f2c49b66        microsoft/mssql-server-linux   "/bin/sh -c /opt/m..."   28 seconds ago      Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp   festive_meninsky
```

Let's go inside and see why it failed the last time:

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ sudo docker exec -it 0031f2c49b66 /bin/bash       
root@0031f2c49b66:/# cd /var/opt/mssql/log/
root@0031f2c49b66:/var/opt/mssql/log# ls
HkEngineEventFile_0_131307476136660000.xel  errorlog    errorlog.2  log_1.trc                  system_health_0_131307476143850000.xel
HkEngineEventFile_0_131307476639820000.xel  errorlog.1  log.trc     setup-20170205-055329.log  system_health_0_131307476647330000.xel
root@0031f2c49b66:/var/opt/mssql/log# cat errorlog.1 
...
2017-02-05 05:53:34.65 spid17s     Server setup is starting
2017-02-05 05:53:34.65 spid17s     Error: 33062, Severity: 16, State: 2.
2017-02-05 05:53:34.65 spid17s     Password validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is too short. The password must be at least 8 characters.
2017-02-05 05:53:34.66 spid17s     An error occurred while setting the server administrator (SA) password: error 33062, severity 16, state 2.
2017-02-05 05:53:34.66 spid17s     An error occurred during server setup. See previous errors for more information.
...
```

Okay. Let's take a glance at the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/). Relevant section:

> A strong system administrator (SA) password: At least 8 characters
>   including uppercase, lowercase letters, base-10 digits and/or
>   non-alphanumeric symbols.

Hmm, let's start from beginning, keeping above in mind:

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ sudo docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e SA_PASSWORD='$uP3RC0mpl3Xp@$$w0rD' -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y microsoft/mssql-server-linux                                                                             
8fcc46d9ae498948dc3cb458fb3169347fcb4f582dc6266b6569f540f2badf1d
```

Let's see if the container runs now:

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8fcc46d9ae49        microsoft/mssql-server-linux   "/bin/sh -c /opt/m..."   8 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp   competent_kalam
```

Let's see if a db connection can be made:

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ tsql -H localhost -p 1433 -P '$uP3RC0mpl3Xp@$$w0rD' -U sa
locale is "C"
locale charset is "ANSI_X3.4-1968"
using default charset "ISO-8859-1"
1> quit
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the answer with the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the password while running the container. If possible check in docker GUI. Cause sometimes due to quotation mark "starting and ending" the container assumes something else as password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).